# How to deduce that something does not follow?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Assume I have formulas $H$, $P$ and $Q$. Assume further that I can 
show in classical logic that $P$ follows from $H$:

$$H \vdash P$$

And that the negation of $Q$ follows from $H$:

$$H \vdash \neg Q$$

Can I then jump to the conclusion that $Q$ does not
follow from $P$:

$$P\not\vdash Q \text{ ?} $$

Bye

Comment: I think this is a good question, and I don't see why anyone would vote to close it as "not a real question".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $H$ is consistent then yes. Assume towards contradiction that this is not the case, then $P\vdash Q$.

1. $P\vdash Q$ implies $\vdash P\rightarrow Q$ using the deduction theorem.
2. Therefore $H\vdash P\land P\rightarrow Q$.
3. And so $H\vdash Q$.

If $H$ is inconsistent (e.g. $0=1$ or $\varnothing\in\varnothing$ sort of thing) then the principle of explosion says that everything is provable from $H$.

Comment: Very nice derivation, thanks. When H is consistent then we cannot have H |- Q and H |- ~Q, therefore also not P |- Q.

Comment: Yes. And say no to intuitionstic logic! :-D

Comment: But we don't have $P \vdash Q$? so how does that apply here?

Comment: @amWhy: Assume by contradiction...

Comment: Asaf: Yes...I see now. Dahhh!

Comment: @amWhy: Oh, but it was a good remark. We all make those small jumps in our minds, it's good to have someone to set us back! (Well except Shelah, he makes huge leaps in his mind.)

Answer (score 4):

No. If $H$ is $0=1$, then you can deduce both $P$ and the negation of $Q$ from $H$, even if, say, $P=Q$.

Answer (score 4):

What you can deduce is $$H \vdash (P \land \lnot Q),\quad\text{that is}\;\;\; H\vdash \lnot(P \rightarrow Q)$$

since $ (P \land \lnot Q)\equiv \lnot(\lnot P \lor  Q) \equiv \lnot (P\rightarrow Q)$